# PHP mail not sending form data. Data is blank in email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Somehow the form is not sending the main data which is basically the name, email and number. I's appreciate any/all help!

Here is the PHP i used.

```
<?php 
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

require_once('geoplugin.class.php');

$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();

//get user's ip address 
$geoplugin->locate();
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { 
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; 
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { 
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; 
} else { 
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
} 


$mess .= "---------------|OFFERS USER EMAIL SUBSCRIPTION|---------------\n";
$mess .= "Full Name  : " . $_POST['cn'] . "\n";
$mess .= "Email Address  : " . $_POST['em'] . "\n";
$mess .= "Number: " . $_POST['pn'] . "\n";
$mess .= "IP Address  : " .$ip. "\n";
$mess .= "--------------------------------------------\n";
$mess .=    "City: {$geoplugin->city}\n";
$mess .=    "Region: {$geoplugin->region}\n";
$mess .=    "Country Name: {$geoplugin->countryName}\n";
$mess .=    "Country Code: {$geoplugin->countryCode}\n";
$mess .= "---------------------------------------------\n";

$from = "XOXLERT";
$to = "mail@mail.com"; 


$hi = mail($to, "OFFERS EMAIL SUBSCRIPTION | ".$ip , $mess);


?>
```

And here goes the HTML Form Element.

```
<div class="row main-form">
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4 class="fc-white ff-primary">Sign up now <span class="">And Save BIG</span> For Later Use</h4>
                  <p class="ff-primary fs-xlarge fc-white">On your Custom Logo & Website</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="rightform"  id="mainBanForm">
                        <form class="jform validate" action="https://placmedia.com/thank_you.php">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="bm-field-top inpt-rel">
                                <!--<label class="">Name</label>-->
                               <span class="user-icon-top"></span> <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="cn" class="required">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="bm-field-top inpt-rel">
                                <!--<label class="">Email</label>-->
                               <span class="user-email-top"></span>  <input type="text" name="em" class="required email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="bm-field-top pnfields">
                                <!--<label class="">Phone Number</label>-->
                                <input type="text" name="pn" id="phone" class="number required" placeholder="Phone Number" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="bm-field-top-nbg whbgnone">
                                <input type="submit" value="Reserve Now"  class="get-button ff-primary">
                            </div>
                          </div>                          

                        </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What i don't understand is why i am receiving just the IP (of course those are pre-populated by the geo-plugin script) and other form data omitted

Comment: Have you tried dumping out just the HTML? Also consider using a library that simplifies sending email such as PHPMailer.

Comment: I am using this for another project and i receive all the contents. But on this particular one, all i receive is the ip. How do you mean "dumping out" the html?

Comment: check the content of your `$_POST` by doing a `print_r($_POST); die;` right after `$browser=...` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Set the form method to POST. HTML forms default to GET method.

Comment: Very helpful. I sure missed that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the method type. You're trying to access via POST yet the default method is GET.

```
 <form class="jform validate" action="https://placmedia.com/thank_you.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: oh how in the world did i miss that? Thanks Cesar

Comment: You're welcome, somethimes small details are easy to miss ;)